# Nested for loops versus Recursion for fixed height Tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, iteration

I understand this is fundamental computer science question and possible match for my question is [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182314/recursion-or-while-loops).

But it doesn't cover two different scenarios I have in my webapp.

I'm dealing with two different Tree-like Array of Objects which have `children` as members. 
Now

1. First tree having fixed height (maximum of 3 levels)
2. Second tree, having any level depth.

**The Structure of both trees is similar to below (it is an Array of Objects, basically a JSON):**

```
0 ---- someKey
|
---- someOtherKey
|
---- children
                0 ---- someKey
                |
                ---- someOtherKey
                |
                ---- children
                              0 ---- someKey
                              |
                              ---- someOtherKey
                              |
                              ---- children []
                1 ---- someKey
                |
                ---- someOtherKey
                |
                ---- children []

1 ---- someKey
|
---- someOtherKey
|
---- children []

2 ---- someKey
|
---- someOtherKey
|
---- children []
```

Now to traverse first tree, I'm using 3 nested for loops, while for second one I'm using recursion to visit each node upto leaves. And so far, I'm getting reasonably fair performance.

**But is there any advantage of using recursion in the first case?**

or

**Where can recursion fall short in case of second tree with variable depth?**

Answer (score 0):

In first case, recursion is worse then loops, advantage and disadvantage depending upon programming language and implementation.
Loop is better then recursion, because it does simple condition check and jump, where recursion involves pushing a stack frame, jumping, returning and popping back from stack.
In second case, recursion is requires because we do know the depth of tree so we can not put that many loops in our code.

Comment: For second case, where depth of tree is indefinite, I'm making tail-recursive calls to visit each node of the tree (so there won't be a fear of exceeding call-stack) but concern here is for using recursive approach in first case where tree is guaranteed to have at max 3 levels of nesting.

Comment: You can implement traversing without using recursion but using our own stack [here link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-preorder-traversal/)

Comment: So there will no issue of 'Stack call exceeding'

Comment: Issue is not in either of the approaches, I'm looking for strong reason to rewrite code for my first case where I've used nested loops, and convert it to recursion so that I can share same code to traverse trees at both places, without compromising performance. (I'm dealing with ~5000 or above nodes in a single tree).

Comment: So go with second approach using our own stack but without recursion. Reason is simple tree depth is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use either method for either case. Recursion will give you simpler code that is easier to maintain and easier to read. There may be a performance cost, but this will likely not be very large, especially if you're able to use tail recursion. It's probably a good idea to start off with recursion and then only move over to loops if there is (i) a need for better performance and (ii) a measurable performance improvement when using loops.